# Load Balancing and Web Images /Thumbimages/Thumbnails

Tags: c#, asp.net, image, webforms, load-balancing

We are planning to introduce Load balancing in our server environment. Our site has lots of thumbnails (Thumbimages) to get displayed on the website. As all the images should be there under Web directory to get displayed on web site, do I need to maintain these TNs in all the servers?

Is there any other way to accomplish this?

Comment: What do you mean maintaining TNs in all the servers?

Comment: @Hatake Kakashi all the TNs will fall under root directory, so on each server it will have its own root directory, if I maintain the TNs under one server and if the request goes to another server, TNs may not be visible correct?

Comment: So, these TNs are auto generated or you can manage them? I mean if you can organize them into one folder, you can simply put it on one server. Then if you want to access those TNs, there are some ways to do this, you can use hot link if no authentication, or write a simple service/handler... to get TNs in authorized folder to display it. Hope this helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, put the images on all the servers. That's the best way of load balancing because it requires less logic to be performed by the load balancer (i.e. no packet inspection) so is fast. Use rsync or similar to keep the images in sync on all nodes.

Answer (score 0):

Just create a central network share for the images. Then point all the web servers to that network shared images folder. The load balancer is just directing the page request to a web server which then loads the images from a network shared folder. So my conclusion is that there is no load balancing logic required for images?